# jQuery - How Do I Assign Unique Functions To Multiple Events Bound To The Same Object?

Tags: jquery, events, bind, gesture

Simple example:

```
$('foo').bind('doubletap swiperight', function() {});
```

So, I am trying to be really efficient. And maybe I am trying to be TOO efficient, but what I want to do is bind the events to the object ONCE, and then say "if swiperight do this. If doubletap do this."

Is this possible??

Thanks for the help in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine the type of event from within the handler function using `event.type`:

```
$('foo').bind('doubletap swiperight', function(e) {
    if (e.type == "doubletap") {
        // tap code
    }
    else if (e.type == "swiperight") {
        // swipe code
    }
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it, i had the same exact thing!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! You rock! I knew there had to be a way!